# Get the id from the URL; PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i've been curious on how to get the id in the url like php?pid=4 and use it in an update statement in sql. Well heres my code but cant get it worked because of undefined variable id which the value is in the url.

my function.php

```
function update_spot(){

$id=$_GET[pid];
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$sql="UPDATE reports SET date_time_started='$_POST[date1]' ,
    date_time_finished=   '$_POST[date2]',
    barangay='$_POST[brgy]',
    street= '$_POST[street]',
    owner='$_POST[owner]', 
cause='$_POST[cause]',
motive='$_POST[motive]',
firfighter='$_POST[firefighter]'. 
civilian='$_POST[civilian]', 
ifirefighter='$_POST[ifirefighter]',
icivilian='$_POST[icivilian]',
occupancy='$_POST[occupancy]',
ed='$_POST[ed]',
alarm='$_POST[alarm]'

where id='".$id."' ";

 if (!mysql_query($sql)){ die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); } ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>alert('sucessful changed try it next time you log 

in.');window.location='view_inbox.php';</script>    <?php
}

}
```

it seems i cant get id in the url. my url show like this in the form php?pid=5

Comment: Caution, code very prone to sql injection

Comment: You have a `.` instead of a `,` after `'$_POST[firefighter]'`

Comment: You should use the `mysqli` or `PDO` library now rather than `mysql`. Make sure you sanitize your inputs otherwise you are basically giving people free reign over your database.

Comment: Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/283366)

Comment: thanks for the observation im bit huggard hehe..well thank you you have help me alot

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be

```
$id = $_GET['pid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Quotes on your $_GET array access

```
$pid = $_GET['pid'];
```

Also, you are mixing $_GET and $_POST. You should use one or the other, depending on your form's method (GET or POST).

You also want to change all the areas you access it. IE

```
barangay = '$_POST[brgy]';
```

This should be, and all other lines after it

```
barangay = $_POST['brgy'];
```

Comment: Your comment about mixing GET and POST is incorrect. You can POST to a URI with GET parameters and each set of data will be available in their respective super global array (`$_GET` and `$_POST`)

Comment: thanks for the reply . now i got this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. civilian='1', ifirefighter='3', icivilian='8', occupancy='Structural', ' at line 7

Comment: I can rephrase to SHOULD to make you happy, but its rather confusing to have both intermixed.

Comment: @Rottingham I don't think so. I'd rather POST data to `someUri?id=123` than attempting to inject `id=123` as a hidden form field or similar

Comment: Your syntax error is because you are trying to concatenate the string improperly. All of the field name = value pairs need corrected.

Comment: @Rottingham Your last point is also incorrect. Within a double-quoted string, array indexes to do not need to be quoted, eg this is ok (from a pure string interpolation view) `"barangay = '$_POST[brgy]'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$pid = isset($_GET['pid']) ? 0 : intval($_GET['pid']) //to avoid problems in this case
```

Answer (score 0):

@Up, in the example above it still should work, but will cause php warning saying that undefined php constant will be assumed as string.

I would dump get global and see if variable is there, eg var_dump($_GET);